# Display things with time with php

Tags: php, mysql, time

I want to display gitfs with a specific timeslot, when I try my method, It display only the old gifts . I want to display gifts dating from now there one week.

```
 $midnight = strtotime("now -7 days");
    $message = '';
    $user = xxx_variable
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM gifts WHERE to_user = ? AND time > ? ORDER BY time DESC limit 1, 25");
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $midnight, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: The `strtotime` function returns a unix timestamp (an integer), is that how the times are stored in your database? E.g. if the time field is actually of the `TIME` or `DATETIME` datatype, comparing it against a unix timestamp will not work directly.

Comment: So what isn't working? What actually happens? Do you get any errors? What is the value of  `$midnight`?

Comment: Time row in database is : varchar(30)

Comment: You have multiple issues. Your time row being in varchar is one of them.

Comment: What I can do ? Modify database row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

you need to use "UNIX_TIMESTAMP".

UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY) -- 7 days ago

```
 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM gifts WHERE to_user = ? AND time > ? ORDER BY time DESC limit 1, 25");

    to 

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM gifts WHERE to_user = ? AND time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY) ORDER BY time DESC limit 1, 25");
```

Comment: I change var(30) row in TIMESTAMP ? Because if no, it's not working ... That display only the old gifts

Comment: this code display last 7 days record what do you want

Comment: Yes it's true, now it's work I have juste replace `DESC limit 1, 25` by `DESC limit 0, 25`

Answer (score 0):

If you want date from the current date then try this.

```
$d=date("Y-m-d");
$midnight = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($d. ' - 7 days'))
```

Comment: Any problem with that??

Comment: Nothings are displaying when I try this

Comment: @ewan can you give me a sample date from your db.

Comment: In my time row in database for gifts time is : 1433801425 (it's an example )

Comment: @ewan  try this `$midnight= strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($d. ' - 7 days')))`

Comment: Not working too , that display only the old gifts ( obtain yesterday )